# Do you know another way to do this "massive" linq filtering?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filtering

This is my code :

```
// I STORE THE USER SELECTED VALUES
IList<string> SelectedCity = (from CheckBox loc in panelCity.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                              where loc.Checked
                              select loc.InputAttributes["value"]).ToList();

IList<string> SelectedCategories = (from CheckBox strut in panelCategories.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                    where strut.Checked
                                    select strut.InputAttributes["value"]).ToList();

// I GET ALL RECORDS
IList<Hotel> Hotels = (from Hotel hotel in new Hotels()
                       orderby hotel.Titolo ascending
                       select hotel).ToList();

// I FILTER THEM
if (SelectedCity.Count > 0)
    Hotels = Hotels.Where(o => o.City != null && SelectedCity.Contains(o.City.UniqueID)).ToList();

if (SelectedCategories.Count > 0)
    Hotels = Hotels.Where(o => o.Category != null && SelectedCategories.Contains(o.Category.UniqueID)).ToList();
```

So, as you can see, I do some queries, storing values selected from users. Than, for each hotel row, I cycling City and Category's arrays.

This, having MANY rows, it's very expencives.

Do you know some other ways to optimize the research?

Comment: Have you tried using `ToList()` only on the final results? Don' forget to change the types of variable while doing that.

Answer (score 4):

Put your cities and categories into a `HashSet<string>` to save on the lookup time:

```
HashSet<string> selectedCities = new HashSet<string>(SelectedCity); 
HashSet<string> selectedCategories = new HashSet<string>(SelectedCategories);
```

Also you don't need to use `ToList()` until you have your query fully assembled, otherwise you are traversing multiple times:

```
var hotels = from Hotel hotel in new Hotels()
             select hotel;

if (SelectedCity.Any())
    hotels = hotels.Where(o => o.City != null && selectedCities.Contains(o.City.UniqueID));

if (SelectedCategories.Any())
    hotels = hotels.Where(o => o.Category != null && selectedCategories.Contains(o.Category.UniqueID));
```

Finally, sorting can be done once you have filtered out all the hotels you don't want so you are sorting less items:

```
hotels = hotels.OrderBy(h=> h.Titolo);
```

And as a last step materialize the results:

```
Hotels = hotels.ToList();
```

Comment: So Are you saying store a list into hashset?

Comment: Yes - given you are looking for cities and categories there should not be any duplicates, hence you can use a hashset for O(1) lookup time.

Comment: @markzzz: one clarification: Are the hotels coming from a database or is this an in-memory collection?

Comment: Hotels() get the collection of element, taken from DB :) The constructor call a stored procedures...

Comment: ideally you want to filter in the database, it will be much slower otherwise - make sure Hotels returns an `IQueryable<Hotel>` and not an in-memory collection, otherwise this will be orders of magnitudes slower

Comment: Also since you (hopefully) will refactor to filtering on the DB directly, skip the `Hashset` step - that is not supported using Linq to Entities etc.

Comment: Uhm...I prefeer filtering on "real-time" instead of having 10000^10 stored procedures stored on DB :)

Comment: @markzzz: If you are using plain SQL / stored procedures you could pass the filters into your stored procedure, or alternatively keep the full hotels collection cached in memory and don't re-query every time.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you could combime your Where clauses into the above Linq statement:

```
IList Hotels = (from Hotel hotel in new Hotels()
                where SelectedCity.Count > 0 && hotel.City != null && SelectedCity.Contains(hotel.City.UniqueID)
                where SelectedCategories.Count > 0 && hotel.Category != null && SelectedCategories.Contains(hotel.Category.UniqueID)
                orderby hotel.Titolo ascending
                select hotel).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only guessing from here, but the big hit would appear to be get all hotels, seeing as you only need city, or category for the follow on query.

If you went for just selcting the required input to get the matching Ids, then select hotels that matched things may improve.

Answer (score 0):

Loading all hotels into memory to perform search is very ineffective; however, if you don't load all the hotels you won't be able to call `Contains()` on the collection. Instead, you can use `PredicateBuilder` from [Joseph Albahari site](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build a predicate which can be used to get only the hotels that match criteria.

```
var inSelectedCities = PredicateBuilder.True<Hotel>();
foreach(var city in SelectedCity)
{
    string temp = city;
    inSelectedCities = inSelectedCities.Or(h => h.City.UniqueId == temp);
}
var inSelectedCategories = PredicateBuilder.True<Hotel>();
foreach(var category in SelectedCategories)
{
    string temp = category;
    inSelectedCategories = inSelectedCategories.Or(h => h.Category.UniqueId == temp)
}
var hotels = Hotels
                .Where(inSelectedCities.Or(inSelectedCategories))
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem is obviously in the Hotels constructor which hits the database.  If that constructor uses LinqToSql or LinqToEntities, you should pass an `Expression<Func<Hotel, bool>>` into there to call from `Queryable.Where` and get some filtering done on the database side.

If that constructor doesn't use Linq, you'll have to communicate the filtering another way... perhaps by passing the criteria lists in.